# Google Charts API get graph object from div

Tags: object, google-visualization

I have drawn several graphs on my webpage using the Google Charts API. If i want to clear them, i can use the chart's clearChart() method. But lets say i have a div with id="mydiv" which has a line chart drawn in it. To clear it, i would have to first get the chart objectcand then call clearChart(). But how do i get the chart object ?

Comment: I want to free up the memory used by that chart, so i would need to call clearChart().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used JavaScript to render charts you should had saved a reference to chart objects to clear them after.

If you do not have those references but have the div behaving as a container them you can remove or clear the div element from browser tree nodes.

```
document.getElementById( 'mydiv' ).innerHTML = '';
```

Please add additional notes for clarification.

Comment: Yes, i did it by saving a reference to them and calling the clearChart() method later. Thanks !!